# bootstrap paragraph formating for different devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, paragraph

Hi I'm fairly new to bootstrap and what I'm trying to achieve is to have a jumbotron on top of my page with different paragraph formatting to accommodate for a background image which takes lets say 30% of full width space.

I have offset my text by `padding-left: 300px;` and it looks fine on desktops but this rule also applies to a paragraph in mobile device mode resulting it being very skinny and tall.

**Is there a way where I can set lets say 3 different paragraphs each showing under certain screen size?**

Comment: Hey i will just tell you some info on whatever i know so far .. you can go through topic called "Media Queries" which will be useful for understanding more on this kind of questions. You should never use pixels if you want to have responsive design...you should always go for "ems" or "percentages". I heard that in rails 4 ..we have new feature called "variants" where we can define style sheets based on device.

Answer (score 0):

Just use media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
{
    p{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:800px)
{
    p{
        padding-left: 100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px)
{
    p{
        padding-left: 300px;
    }
}
```